# Keyboard issues with Android Studio on Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, ubuntu-14.04

While using Android Studio on Ubuntu there are scenarios where the IDE will stop responding to keyboard input or start inputting random characters?

How to fix this? Or possible workarounds.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[This is a known issue with](http://tools.android.com/knownissues/ibus):

> The bug seems to be triggered by some missing synchronization between
>   IBus (the server) and Xlib + AWT (the client JVM), exposed by a
>   combination of a quick succession of key presses and the client’s
>   slower event handling.

The 2 workarounds that helped me were:

> **Workaround #1**: Force ibus in synchronous mode
>
> ```
> $ IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1 ibus-daemon -xrd
> ```
>
> Do this preferably before starting Studio. This workaround was
>   suggested in https://code.google.com/p/ibus/issues/detail?id=1733 for
>   a different Java application facing the same problems.
>
> **Workaround #2:** Disable IBus input in Studio
>
> ```
> $ XMODIFIERS= ./bin/studio.sh
> ```
>
> This will only disable input methods for Studio, not the other
>   applications. Restarting the daemon while Studio is running
>   (‘ibus-daemon -rd’) effectively disables the input methods for all
>   other applications, and can also crash Studio's JVM with a
>   segmentation fault.

Comment: alias androidStudio='XMODIFIERS= `which studio.sh`'

Comment: tried both workaround but still getting balloon regarding IBus

Comment: That is a warning balloon if I am getting what you are saying. The problem is with the daemon we are using and that persists. These are just workarounds.

Comment: Where and how do I add this?

Comment: @JonasB Just open the terminal (ctrl+alt+T) and fire the commands.

Comment: Can somebody help me with the same issue in mac as well?

Comment: i just fired this command `XMODIFIERS= ./bin/studio.sh` but got no such adirectory messgae

Answer (score 1):

`File -> Invalidate Catches / Restart` works for me.

Comment: For me, just restarting the IDE works, to save waiting on the invalidate/cache restart indexing.

Comment: How come this is a solution?

Comment: Turgut Sarıçam what do expect from a solution? or what is your definition of a solution? whatever solves a problem is considered a solution to that problem. I tested it and worked for me. that's all.

Comment: I expect a solution to fix the problem, not hide it for a while.

Comment: This does not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Restart the Android Studio.
Everytime it'll restart the keyboard will start working well.

This is a know issue **[Frozen keyboard input - "iBus" problems on Linux][1]**

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the IDE work in ubuntu 2020 Edison.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only thing that worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04.

- Close the Android Studio (if open)
- Delete the `Home/.android` directory
- Open Android Studio
- Go to `File > Invalidate Caches/Restart`
- Click the **Invalidate and Restart** button

> I also deleted the project level `.idea` folder, can't say for sure if that did anything. You may try it.