# AndroidManifest.xml not editable on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest, reverse-engineering

[image]

I've been reversing an app, but came across a problem. The AndroidManifest.xml file is not writable.
I made sure that the file is not 'read-only' in file explorer, but it still doesn't work. And I can't find 'merged text tab(?)' sort of thing which is supposed to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey there can be multiple ways you can try to solve this issue:

1. The simplest one is to Clean and Rebuild the project.
2. You can go to your File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart.
3. Try running Android Studio in Administrator mode.
4. You can try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34705198/9062752

**Let me know if any of these fixed your error.**

*Also note : Not sure about this library but I read a comment which says ".jar files cannot be edited", so yeah if you are trying to edit a .jar file it is not possible (I am not sure of the reason though)*

Comment: None of it worked, but thanks anyway. Decompiling the apk with apktool did the trick

Answer (score 0):

dear please check your menifest file that you can show build version name and build version code in application class please remove it and check any error in your menifest file and than you can run or rebuild your project .